# strcpy_s を使用すると undefine reference to 'strcpy_s' エラーが発生する

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

課題にて `strcpy_s` を使用して文字列をコピーしなくてはならないのですが
undefine reference to 'strcpy_s'とエラーが出てしまって実行できません。
`strcpy` は問題なく使用することができます。

一時間ほどエラーコードなど検索してはいるのですが、力不足で解決には至っておりません。

解説等いただけると幸いです。

環境
Ubuntu 20.04
eclipse IDE

以下にコードを記載します。

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
char A[10];
char B[10];

printf("文字列の入力\n");

scanf("%s",B);

printf("文字列を代入します\n");

strcpy_s(A,sizeof(A),B);//実行できません
//strcpy(A,B);//実行できます
//strncpy(A,B,sizeof(A));//実行できます

printf("A = %s",A);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: コンパイラは何を使用しているか分かりますか？ (例: gcc 等)

Answer (score 6):

`strcpy_s()` はもともと `Microsoft Visual C / C++` にて採用された新しい関数です。そのため `MSVC` 以外の処理系には `strcpy_s()` は実装されていないのが多いようです。

[c11](/questions/tagged/c11) つまり C の言語仕様書 ISO/IEC 9899:2011 では確かオプショナルで採用されたのですが [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) 開発グループはこの関数を [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) に（今は）実装しないことを決定している様子。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045973/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723946/
そのため [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) 開発グループが提供している libc では `strcpy_s()` は使えないです。つまり Ubuntu の libc では `strcpy_s()` は使えません（[gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) , [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) とも）

課題なら開発環境の指定もあるはず。 Visual Studio なら素直に通るはずでが、指定されていませんか？

---

`strcpy_s()` が Ubuntu の libc に無い、でも Ubuntu 上で使いたい、ということなら

- 自作する
- 既に完成しているソースコードを使わせてもらう
- 既に完成しているライブラリを使わせてもらう

あたりの選択肢があります。既にコメントにある通り `safeclib`を使ってもよさそうだし `MSVC` から `.h` と `.c` (`.cpp` かも未確認) をコピーしてもよさそうだし。 `strcpy_s()` の仕様解説はあちこちにあるわけでそれをもとに自作できれば最も勉強になるでしょう。

Eclipse は Windows でも動くので、動作プラットフォームは Windows10 統合開発環境は Eclipse コンパイラとライブラリは MSVC ってのも大いにありですよ？

まあ課題なら Visual Studio 上でちゃっちゃと済ませてしまえばおしまいなので、そこまで手間（＝コスト）をかけなくてもいいんぢゃね？　とかは秘かに思ったりします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど…
VisualStudioもあるのでそちらの方でも試してみようと思います。 また重ねての質問になってしまうのですが、
'どうしても'
eclipse上でstrcpy_sを実装したい場合
無理やりコードを通す、関数を追加する方法など
ありませんでしょうか？

Comment: @user40920 さん、こちらの [using c11 standard with clang for use of strcpy_s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57915149/9014308) でコメントに出ていた [rurban/safeclib](https://github.com/rurban/safeclib) を試してみるのはどうでしょう？

Comment: どうしても eclipseでやりたいのであれば、strcpy_sを自分で作成すれば可能です。コピー元からコピー先へバッファーサイズをオーバーしない範囲で1文字ずつコピーしていくような関数を作成すればいいと思います。

Comment: みなさん。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。
個人的な都合ではありますが、現在の環境にて
課題をする必要があるので
今回教えていただいたものを参考に
色々勉強しようと思います！

Answer (score 5):

> **どうしても**eclipse上でstrcpy_sを実装したい場合無理やりコードを通す、関数を追加する方法など ありませんでしょうか？？

774RRさんも回答されていますが、`strcpy_s`はC言語仕様に載ってはいるもののオプショナルであり、現状ではMicrosoftのVisual Studioぐらいでしか提供されていません。
質問者さん以外の第三者としては「課題にて`strcpy_s`を使用して文字列をコピーしなくてはならない」が実際にどのような記述で出題されているのかはわかりませんが、課題の内容をもう一度深く深く読み返すことをお勧めします。（`strcpy_s`を使用しなくてもよい、もしくはVisual Studioの利用が必須、等の条件が課されているのではと推測しています。）

といいますのも、質問文では`printf`や`scanf`を利用されていますが、こちらも[`printf_s`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)や[`scanf_s`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)が用意されており、`strcpy_s`の使用が必須なのであれば同様に`printf_s`や`scanf_s`の使用も必須になるはずです。

また、C言語仕様に載っている`_s`系関数と、Visual Studioで提供される`_s`系関数とでは微妙に仕様の異なる点があるため、どちらの使用が求められているのかも明確にしておいた方がいいでしょう。

---

なお、C言語ではなくC++言語向けですが、質問とは逆方向の機能として[セキュリティ保護されたテンプレート オーバーロード](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-runtime-library/secure-template-overloads?view=vs-2019)がVisual Studioでは提供されています。
`_CRT_SECURE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_NAMES`を`1`に設定すると

```
char A[10];
strcpy(A, B);
```

は`strcpy_s(A, sizeof A, B);`としてコンパイルされるため、`strcpy_s`を持たない環境とソースコードの互換性を持たせたまま少しだけセキュリティ保護を強化することができます。

Comment: 外野からすみませんが、そんな便利なテンプレートがあるんですね。